# partial match between two arrays in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I have two arrays:

```
a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a2 = ['a_111', 'd_111']
```

how can I loop thorough array and do a partial match to find the difference is

```
['b', 'c']
```

and add `'b_111'`, `'c_111'` to array `a2`?

Is there any particular way to do it in python?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension/`list.extend` and `all`:

```
>>> a2 += [x + '_111' for x in a1 if all(x not in y for y in a2)]
>>> a2
['a_111', 'd_111', 'b_111', 'c_111']
```

**or:**

```
>>> a2.extend(x + '_111' for x in a1 if all(x not in y for y in a2))
```

If you want `['b', 'c']` as well, then you can break the above code into two steps:

```
>>> partial =  [x for x in a1 if all(x not in y for y in a2)]
>>> partial
['b', 'c']
>>> a2 += [x + '_111' for x in partial]
>>> a2
['a_111', 'd_111', 'b_111', 'c_111']
```